# Trimmer javascript, is it correct to use it like this?

Tags: javascript

I don't know how this construction is called but may be trimmer.

```
someCondition ?  function1() : function2();
```

JsHint says that he expected an assigment or function and instead saw an expression.
So i am wondering will it work in all browsers correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is called the [conditional (ternary) operator `?:`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) and it is actually equivalent to:

```
 if (someCondition) {
     function1();
 }
 else {
     function2();
 }
```

The fact that JsHint doesn't like it doesn't mean that it is not a valid syntax, it just means it is bad style but it will work nevertheless.

Answer (score 1):

You could try it yourself

```
true ? console.log('a') : console.log('b')
```

This is a ternary operator, what JSHint is telling you is that using ternary operators like this might be confusing. JSHint is pretty opinionated and won't only warn you about things that might break the code, but also about things that the author didn't like.

If you'd prefer a leaner linter (unopinionated) you might want to try out the [recently released ESLint](http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2013/07/16/introducing-eslint/)

Generally speaking, you should be using ternary operators in *assignments*, rather than for function calls.

My approach is the following:

```
if (something) {
    fn1();
} else {
    fn2();
}
```

In the case of assignments this is fine:

```
var foo = something ? 'foo' : 'bar';
```

A possible alternative to the first example would be:

```
var foo = {

    fn1: fn1,
    fn2: fn2
};

foo[bar ? 'fn1' : 'fn2']();
```

This, however, is probably even more confusing in most real scenarios.